# Doctrine mongoDB get only one field

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

i have a this document:

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 542e6f6f10f0ed75138b4567
)
[description] => Lorem...
[lat] => 37.5184124
[lng] => 15.015836000000036
[name] => My company
[phone] => +4977665556
[photos] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [_id] => MongoId Object (
            [$id] => 542e6f7a10f0ed73138b4567
        )
        [image] => 06c2aeb0a8fbc03b7c77732166114a23.jpg
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [_id] => MongoId Object (
            [$id] => 542e6f7c10f0ed77138b4568
        )
        [image] => a7a428c48291137bade2fd81c842c5ab.jpg
    )
)
```

Now i want get only array `photos` with Doctrine ODM.

I tried this query, but not working:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('Company')
            ->select('photos')
            ->field('ID')->equals($id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
```

This query return all document not only `photos`.

**Why?**

Answer (score 3):

Using `Builder::select()` to project a specific field does not mean that the query will return that field alone. The Company's query builder will always return Company objects. In your case, `getSingleResult()` has the query return a single object instead of an iterable cursor of Company objects. The `select()` projection means that the MongoDB query will only return the `_id` and `photos` fields, which will then be hydrated into a Company object.

As a result, you'll find that `Company::getName()` probably returns `null`, while `Company::getPhotos()` probably returns a `PersistentCollection` of Photo objects. It's unclear to me from your example if those are referenced or simply embedded documents with an `_id` field.

By default, ODM hydrates query results. This can be problematic when you're using projections to exclude fields, as any further assignments to non-hydrated fields might be picked up as a change and persisted back to the database. If you're rather obtain the raw data, you can disable hydration with via `Builder::hydrate()`, which takes a boolean.

On a side note, I'd suggest you use `'id'` or `'_id'` instead of `'ID'` in your `field()` query. I'm not sure if ODM does a case-insensitive string comparison when it looks up mapped fields -- unless of course your PHP property is `$ID`, in which case you can ignore this suggestion.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to get a field in doctrine? I have a mapped object in a field and I want to get only these mapped objects.

Comment: If you're referring to [field projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), the relevant ODM documentation is [Selecting Fields](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/query-builder-api.html#selecting-fields) in the query builder documentation.

Comment: Call to a member function getQuery() on null when i do $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('EventFollower') ->select('id')->getQuery()->execute()->toArray()

Comment: Assuming you're using ODM 1.x, [`Doctrine\MongoDB\Query\Builder::select()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/1.6.3/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php#L1438) is a fluent API method that returns the builder object, so it's not clear how `null` would be returned. This behavior is the same for [`select()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/2.0.0-alpha1/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php#L1344) in ODM's 2.x branch. If this is still outstanding, I would suggest reporting it with a full backtrace on the [mongodb-odm](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) repository.